# JTextPane append logs instantly line per line

Tags: java, swing, log4j, awt, jtextpane

I am actually writing all my log4j logs in my graphic application with JTextPane. It is working without any problem but actually it is not writing instantly my logs (I mean it is waiting that all the logs are generated and then write them at once at the end in my application).

How can I write instantly every new log line ?

MainLogger

```
public class MainLogger {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Logger");

    private static boolean init = false;

    private MainLogger(){}

    public static void init(Appender appender,Level l){
        if (init != true){
            log.addAppender(appender);
            log.setLevel(l);
        }
        init = true;
    }


    public static void logWarn(final String s){     
        log.warn(s);
    }

    public static void logError(final String s){
        log.error(s);       
    }

    public static void logError(final Throwable ex){
        log.fatal(new String(),ex);
    }

    public static void logTrace(final String s){
        log.trace(s);
    }

}
```

FlexibleLayout

```
public class FlexibleLayout extends Layout {

    private String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    @Override
    public void activateOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(event.getLevel().toString()).append(": ");
//      sb.append("[")
//      .append(event.getLocationInformation().fullInfo)
//      .append("] :");

        sb.append(event.getMessage()).append(NL);
        if (event.getThrowableInformation() != null){
            String[] s = event.getThrowableStrRep();
            for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                sb.append(s[i]).append(NL);
            }           
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ignoresThrowable() {     
        return false;
    }

}
```

JTextPaneAppender

```
public class JTextPaneAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

    private JTextPane _jtextpane = null;

    public Style _styleNormal;
    public Style _styleBold;
    public Style _styleRed; 
    public Style _styleBlue;    

    private Layout _pl = new FlexibleLayout();

    private JTextPaneAppender(){}
    public JTextPaneAppender(JTextPane j){
        super();
        _jtextpane = j;

         StyledDocument doc= _jtextpane.getStyledDocument();

         _styleNormal=doc.addStyle("regular", null);
         StyleConstants.setForeground(_styleNormal, Color.BLACK);

         _styleBlue=doc.addStyle("blue", null);
         StyleConstants.setForeground(_styleBlue, Color.BLUE);

         _styleBold=doc.addStyle("bold", _styleNormal);
         StyleConstants.setBold(_styleBold, true);
         _styleRed=doc.addStyle("red", _styleBold);
         StyleConstants.setForeground(_styleRed, Color.RED);                
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {         
        String toLog = _pl.format(event);
        if (_jtextpane != null){
            if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.ERROR)) logError(toLog);
            else if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.FATAL)) logFatal(toLog);
            else if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.WARN)) logWarning(toLog);
            else if (event.getLevel().equals(Level.TRACE)) logTrace(toLog);
         }      
    }

    private void logTrace(String s){
        log(s,_styleNormal);
    }

    private void logWarning(String s){
        log(s,_styleBlue);
    }

    private void logFatal(String s){
        logError(s);
    }

    private void logError(String s){
            log(s,_styleRed);           
    }

    private void log(String s, Style style){
        if (s== null) return;
        if (_jtextpane == null) return;
        StyledDocument doc= _jtextpane.getStyledDocument();
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s, style);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {} 
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresLayout() {       
        return false;
    }



}
```

TestFrame

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel jContentPane = null;

    private JScrollPane jScrollPane = null;

    private JTextPane jTextPane = null;

    private JButton jButton = null;

    private JPanel jPanel = null;

    private JButton jButton1 = null;

    private JButton jButton2 = null;

    private JButton jButton3 = null;

    /**
     * This method initializes jScrollPane  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JScrollPane  
     */
    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {
        if (jScrollPane == null) {
            jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            jScrollPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
            jScrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
            jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 300));
            jScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "JtextPane Log", TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12), new Color(51, 51, 51)));
            jScrollPane.setViewportView(getJTextPane());
        }
        return jScrollPane;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jTextPane    
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JTextPane    
     */
    private JTextPane getJTextPane() {
        if (jTextPane == null) {
            jTextPane = new JTextPane();
            jTextPane.setEditable(false);
            jTextPane.addCaretListener(new javax.swing.event.CaretListener() {
                public void caretUpdate(javax.swing.event.CaretEvent e) {
                    String s = getJTextPane().getText();
                    System.out.println(s.length()); // TODO Auto-generated Event stub caretUpdate()
                }
            });
        }
        return jTextPane;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jButton  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getJButton() {
        if (jButton == null) {
            jButton = new JButton();
            jButton.setText("AddError");            
            jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    MainLogger.logError("An Error");

                    }
            });
        }
        return jButton;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jPanel   
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel   
     */
    private JPanel getJPanel() {
        if (jPanel == null) {
            jPanel = new JPanel();
            jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(getJPanel(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            jPanel.add(getJButton(), null);
            jPanel.add(getJButton1(), null);
            jPanel.add(getJButton2(), null);
            jPanel.add(getJButton3(), null);
        }
        return jPanel;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jButton1 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getJButton1() {
        if (jButton1 == null) {
            jButton1 = new JButton();
            jButton1.setText("Add Exception");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        throw new Exception("This is a custom exception");
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        MainLogger.logError(e1);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton1;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jButton2 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getJButton2() {
        if (jButton2 == null) {
            jButton2 = new JButton();
            jButton2.setText("Add Warning");
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    MainLogger.logWarn("This is a warning!!");
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton2;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jButton3 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getJButton3() {
        if (jButton3 == null) {
            jButton3 = new JButton();
            jButton3.setText("Add Trace");
            jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    MainLogger.logTrace("This is a Trace message!");
                }
            });
        }
        return jButton3;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                TestFrame thisClass = new TestFrame();
                thisClass.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                thisClass.setVisible(true);
                MainLogger.init(
                        new JTextPaneAppender(thisClass.getJTextPane()),
                        org.apache.log4j.Level.TRACE);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This is the default constructor
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private void initialize() {
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jContentPane
     * 
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJContentPane() {
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jContentPane.add(getJScrollPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            jContentPane.add(getJPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }

}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,10"
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to do thé appending in the EDT. Use a SwingWorker.